# Which Visual Studio for Mac can I Install?

Tags: visual-studio

I came across 2 different options for Mac at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com. Visual Studio created specifically for Mac and Visual Studio for any device. Which one do you think I should install for Mac?

Comment: What do you mean by "Visual Studio for any device"? Do you mean "Visual Studio Code"? (That's not the same as Visual Studio by any means.) Note that excessive bolding makes your post harder to read than no bolding at all.

Comment: Fundamentally there's a lot of information on that page already - you haven't given us *any* context for what you're trying to develop, which makes it hard for anyone to say anything that isn't already on that page...

Answer (score 0):

The only version of Visual Studio you can install on Mac is called "Visual Studio for Mac".

You can also install a different product called "Visual Studio Code" which is vastly different than Visual Studio.

Comment: I know, but which one is better?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. Some people prefer Code because it is faster. But it has less features. It also depends on what programming languages are you going to use. Code is better suited towards Web development, but can also handle c++/c# etc.

Comment: Got it, so Visual Studio for Mac is better for me. Thank you. I am new here.